# c# integer's size is the value of another integer

Tags: c#

I'm describing a file in `c#` and the size of a certain int is the 2 * the value of another file. How can I code this?

I tried `sizeof()` and `marshall.sizeof()` but it didn't work.

```
public UInt32 EntryCount  { get; set;  }
public uint BoneID { get; set; }
```

and the BoneID needs to be 2 * the value of EntryCount.

Comment: When you say 'value of another file' do you mean the amount of hard disk space it is using? You should also post some of the code you tried already

Comment: Post still makes not much sense.... Are you by any chance use word "file" as synonym for "field"? ( they are really different)

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like:

```
new FileInfo(filepath).Length * 2
```

Comment: well, by "File", I mean another int. Ex: `public UInt32 EntryCount
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public uint BoneID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }` where BoneID's size needs to be 2 * the value of the entry point.

Comment: Huh? That makes no sense, please see [ask]

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: @iSYan sample of the data (in valid C#) you are trying to write to file (small, see [MCVE] how to show code samples) would likely be better than trying to describe what you are doing...

Comment: `public UInt32 EntryCount
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public uint BoneID
            {
                get;
                set;
            }`

Comment: Sorry I'm even more confused now, 2 times the value of entry point or EntryCount? It's best you [edit] your question and include the code that doesn't work

Comment: 2 times the value of EntryCount

Comment: @Jeremy_Thompson So what should I do?

Comment: Add a method to the class where you declared the variables and in it write the calculation: **BoneID = EntryCount * 2;**